# Python method from imported script not recognised

Tags: python, object

I am using anaconda notebook as my main python tool. I have a script called `tree.py` and a notebook test.ipynb

this is what I have in `tree.py`:

```
class bst(object):
   def __init__(self,val):
      self.val = val
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
   def setleft(self,l):
      l = bst(l)
      self.left = l
```

I imported it in the ipynb and tried to do this:

```
s = tree.bst(2)
s.setleft(3)
```

and it gave me an AttributeError saying "bst object has no attribute setleft". What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

In the second file you've created, put in this line of code at the beginning (please make sure that the two files are in the same directory)

```
import tree
```

and after write:

```
s = tree.bst(2)
s.setleft(3)
```